# How to create files using JavaScript in GitHub?

Tags: javascript, github, github-pages

I am hosting my website on [Github pages](https://pages.github.com/) and want to create a TXT file for some user data when someone logs in to my website. I used the fs module to create a file but it didn't work. I think fs doesn't work on Github. Here's my example code-

```
var fs = require('fs');
var DATA= "blah blah blah";
fs.writeFile("USERDATA.txt", DATA)
```

I don't know too much about JS so ⬆⬆(the code) can be wrong(If it's wrong please tell me).

I know the [Github API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest) but didn't find tutorials that could solve my problem.
If you know something about the Github API that would solve my problem pls tell me.

Comment: Create files how? Where? What does "in github" mean? May you share a [mcve] of what you're trying to do?

Comment: The Github API is not suitable for solving your problem. Github Pages is not suitable for hosting this kind of website.